# move cursor from one div text field to another div text field in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I know its already being asked several times and know how to get focus but having doubt if text field is inside div how can we make it focus

here is the code please have a look

```js
$(".inputs").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group multiple">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Number From:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 in">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" name="number_from" id="number_from" Placeholder="Enter Number...">
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Number To:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 in">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" name="number_to" id="number_to" Placeholder="Enter Number...">

  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->

<div class="form-group qu">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantity :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7 in">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" autocomplete="off" required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" name="quantity" id="quantity" Placeholder="Enter Quantity...">
  </div>
</div>
```

here  the max length is 3 and and if limit reaches it should go to next text field so that i gave my code like this

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
  $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
}
});
```

But its not going to next field please help me to solve

Answer (score 0):

Hello @user_777 I think what you are inferring here is you want an autofocus on the first input field and as it exceed it's maxlength it should shift autofocus to the next input field.

**That i was able to help you fix with the code snippet below:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>A test site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(".inputs").keyup(function() {
            if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
                $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
            }
        });

        //Tab autofocus script
        function autotab(current, to) {
            if (current.getAttribute && current.value.length == current.getAttribute("maxlength")) {
                to.focus()
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="form-group multiple">
        <form name="formName">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Number From:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3 in">
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" oninput="autotab(this, document.formName.number_to)" autofocus name="number_from" id="number_from" Placeholder="Enter Number...">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Number To:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3 in">
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" oninput="autotab(this, document.formName.quantity)" name="number_to" id="number_to" Placeholder="Enter Number...">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group qu">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantity :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7 in">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" autocomplete="off" required onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" name="quantity" id="quantity" Placeholder="Enter Quantity...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end -->


</body>

</html>
```

I hope I was able to help.